# How long will it take for pink skin after the falling of the scab to return to normal colouration?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, coloration-discoloration, wound-care, scar-tissue-scars, scab

About two weeks ago, I had a (minor) accident which thankfully did not result in any major damage to my bones or my joints, but which did leave me with a rather large wound near and below my elbow. It was after 9 days that the dark brown scab covering it fell off, some two days after a liberal dabbing of Soframycin (framycetin sulphate).Though the region looks and also feels infinitely healthier, the skin where the scab once was has turned pink and in some places is even almost reddish.

So I have three questions:

1) Is the pink pigmentation any cause for alarm or is it natural in skin after scabs?

2) Is the colour going to return to normal naturally or I get it treated (if there is a treatment) by a dermatologist?

3) Is there any cream/lotion/other medication that could encourage and/or speed up the process?

Also, I have shown the pink patch of skin to my closest friend, and upon his advice, I apply palm oil to it twice each day. Is that a good idea or should I discontinue it?